# The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through a Rails tutorial and currently at the CRUD section.  There seems to have been some changes from Rails 3 to 4 in regards to the Create action.  The tutorial is using Rails 3.x.x and I'm using Rails 4.1.2.  I have attempted to adapt my posts controller but I'm getting this error.

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
    @category = Category.all
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been saved"
    else
        render "new"
    end
    Category.create(category_params)
end

def edit

end

def update

end

def destroy

end

private

def category_params
    params.require(:name).permit(:id)
end

def create
    Post.create(post_params)
end

private

def post_params

    params.require(:title, :body, :category_id, :author_id)

end

end
```

models/posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
end
```

I can tell that the post contoller is wrong but nothing I have tried has worked.

**UPDATE**

Server log for create action

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-24 19:52:22 -0400
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w/ViBIFCFaaT1yIZaBkjWhjUjZ0LKXrT+9sOIN0c2q4=", "post"=>{"title"=>"teste", "body"=>"testest", "category_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Add Post"}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, post, commit
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-06-24 23:52:22.825483"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-24 23:52:22.825483"]]
  [1m[36m (1.3ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://domain:3000/posts
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, post, commit
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2014-06-24 23:52:22.828618"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-24 23:52:22.828618"]]
  [1m[35m (1.1ms)[0m  commit transaction
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

Comment: You have two create methods defined.

Comment: Yeah thats the first thing i'm assuming is wrong, along with the fact that the second is private.

Comment: No you can't have two methods with the same name like that. The one specified last in the file will override the latter. The reason why the 2nd `create` causes an error is because it is private and therefore doesn't exist to the router in your application

Comment: We need to see the params from the server log. To see what is receiving the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two create methods, and one is private. So you ruby can't access to it.

Edit: I've added the params permit. You doesn't seem to be sending this id.

Your controller should look like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @category = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been saved"
    else
        render "new"
    end
    Category.create(category_params)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:category_id)
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :author_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried this before and I get the error "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError" traced to `@post = Post.new(params[:post])`.  I also tried changing the post_params method to `params.require` with the same result.

Comment: Edited Check Post.new

Comment: So that fixes that error but brought me to an error with `category_params`.  I guess I am requiring :name but only sending :id.  So I changed the category params to remove `.require(:name)` and left only `params.permit(:id)`.  Now the errors are gone and I'm redirected back to :3000/posts but it seems the post saved is empty with only an id.

Comment: Paste your params request for this action in the question.

Comment: I've changed the methods to you params. But you will have to check your form. You are not sending the author_id that you permited. That should be enough for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is a mess. It has two "create" actions and two "private" declarations. Use scaffold generator to generate a Controller for you. Read up more on that here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Comment: Thanks.  I will eventually scaffold things but I'm at the very beginning just trying to get a grasp.

Comment: It's a good idea to learn from the scaffolds as example. For instance: `rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text`.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Params**

You need to use [`strong params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) in Rails 4:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
       parmas.require(:post).permit(:param1, :param2, :param3, :param4)
   end
end
```

--

**Routes**

Secondly, you need to consider [`resourceful` routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

When you use routing in Rails, the default is to create routes *around* particular "resources" (I.E around controllers / models). Basically, the routes you have will work like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts
```

You may know this already, but as you're following the tutorial, you'll be able to see how the routing mechanism works, allowing you to route your paths accordingly

[image]

Something you need to also consider is, as `@san` pointed out, you need to make sure you only have one resourceful route per controller (you currently have two `create` actions)